# Java static variable and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a base class where I have a static variable defined. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596955/java-static-variables-and-inheritance-and-memory) I know every class extending the base class will have the same copy of the class variable (static variable). Is there a way to make each extending class have it own "copy of the class variable"? I tried declaring the base class abstract but no luck.

```
public abstract class BaseBlah{
    private static int number_of_threads;

} 

public class Blah1 extends BaseBlah{

}
public class Blah2 extends BaseBlah{

}
```

My case is a little more complicated than the example since I want each extended class to abstract one common type of tasks executed in its dedicated thread pool which is the class variable in this case.

Comment: You use 'private' modifier. Subclasses cannot see it. Instead use 'protected'

Comment: Thanks @JustasŠpakauskas. Would declaring it protected make all the subclasses have their own copy of the class variable?

Comment: If it is static - No. All subclasses will refer to the same variable in memory. Thats why static modifier is being used for. Do not use static if you need all subclasses to have instance variables.

Answer (score 7):

Every class will have it's own copy if you give it a copy of the field, but not automagically.

```
public abstract class BaseBlah{
    private static int number_of_threads;

} 

public class Blah1 extends BaseBlah{
    private static int number_of_threads;

}
public class Blah2 extends BaseBlah{
    private static int number_of_threads;

}
```

All the classes have their own copy of `number_of_threads`

Note: this would be called `hiding` if the fields were not private rather than inheritance.
`

Comment: @brotherofmysister most likely the cleaner way is to not create so many sub-classes.  There is no way in Java to say at all sub-classes must have a particular constructor, static fields, or static method, and there is usually another way to achieve this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey +1 for discouraging from inheritance. Abstractions is the key!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-hacky way to do it, using a `HashMap` in the base class:

```
public abstract class BaseBlah{
    private static HashMap<Class<? extends BaseBlah>, Integer> numThreadsMap = new HashMap<>();

    protected int getNumThreads() {
         Integer i = numThreadsMap.get(getClass());
         return i != null ? i : 0;
    }

    protected void setNumThreads(int n) {
        numThreadsMap.put(getClass(), n);
    }
}
```

The upside of this is that there's nothing to remember for future implementing classes of `BaseBlah`. Whenever you create a new extending class it will "automatically" create a new "static" variable for the class.

The downside is that in order to use this approach you have to access it from a non static context (i.e. with an instance). It will behave as a static variable, but you can't treat it as such. `static` and class extension don't like each other (as this example proves) so fully integrating the two is always messy.

Comment: You can use `ClassValue` to implement this cleaner. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassValue.html It cleans up when classes are unloaded